# Position form in centre of fixed overlay

Tags: css, position

I am trying to position a form containing a table in the centre of an overlay with position fixed in css.

I also want it to stay in the centre when the page is resized or when the user scrolls - move with the page.

This is what I have:

```
<div id="overlay">
    <form class="overlay-form" method='POST' id="form"...>
        <table id="form" class="overlay-table">
        ...
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
#overlay {
     position: fixed;
     left: 0px;
     top: 0px;
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     text-align:center;
     /*there is also a centered background image*/
}
#overlay div {
     width:800px;
     text-align:center;
}
form.overlay-form {
     width:780px;
}
table.overlay-table {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: `#overlay div` rule is useless (based on your HTML code)

Comment: @Fabio why is this isn't the # referring to the id?

Comment: this rule is applied to all div elements inside the element with id "overlay"... but there aren't divs inside it (maybe inside table, but I don't think you want 800px width for them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project is not covering older browsers, you can make use of the **[Flexbox model](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)** and some relative dimension metrics such as `vw` and `vh`. More information about `vw / vh` **[here.](https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/)**

> **NOTE:** For further information on the flexbox properties I am using follow the link above.

Meaning, you should try the following flexbox approach that will center everything for you:

```
#overlay {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
   text-align:center;
   /*Flexbox*/
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   align-content: center;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

And you should use the **[Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/)** to make this work across all modern browsers.

Comment: My pleasure. Cheers!